# Implementing drag and drop using dnd library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am using the below code. I am being able to drag but not drop. How to call the dropFunction on drop is my question ?

```
Drag code:
            <div>
            <a class="button" ng-class="{editing: mode == modes.edit_rows}" ng-repeat="col in definition.columns" ng-click="editColumn($index)"
                dnd-type="'columnPills'" 
                dnd-draggable="event"
                dnd-effect-allowed="copy"
                dnd-copied=""
                dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                dnd-moved="moveAndDeletePills(definition.rows,$index)">{{name.toString()}}</a></div>

Drop code:
            <div dnd-allowed-types="'columnPills'"
            dnd-drop="dropFunction(event, index, item, external, type, definition)"
            dnd-dragover="true"
            dnd-droppable="true">
            </div>
```

I even tried calling the drop function dropFunction() without any arguments but still the function is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sjm for the answer but in addition to the callback we also have to make sure we use dnd-list on the drop code because the dnd library works only on a list.

Also the list has to be passed as arguement and the new object that is being dropped will be added to the list.

After research and executing the code I am happy to share the correct code.

```
Drag Code:
                 <div>
                 <li class="button" ng-class="{editing: mode == modes.edit_rows}" ng-repeat="col in definition.columns" ng-click="editColumn($index)"
                 dnd-type="'col'" 
                 dnd-draggable="col"
                 dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                 dnd-moved="moveAndDeletePills(definition.rows,$index)">{{name.toString()}}</li>               
                 </div>


Drop Code:
        <div dnd-allowed-types="'col'"
        dnd-list="definition.rows"
        dnd-drop="dropFunction(event, index, item, external, type, definition)"
        dnd-dragover="true"
        dnd-droppable="true">

        <li class="button" ng-repeat="row in definition.rows" ng-click="editRow($index)"</li>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you return the 'item' in the callback? i.e.

```
  $scope.dropCallback = function(event, index, item, external, type, allowedType) {
    if (external) {
        ...
        return false;
    }
    return item;
  };
```

Below is from the Documentation, note where it says "it must return the object that will be inserted"

"dnd-drop Optional expression that is invoked when an element is dropped over the list. If the expression is set, it must return the object that will be inserted into the list. If it returns false, the drop will be aborted and the event is propagated."

https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists